# ActiveAdmin Change Default Sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

ActiveAdmin sorts the index for all resources based on id. i.e. ActiveAdmin's default sort order is `id_desc`.
Is there a way to change this to `created_at_desc`?

Instead of adding `config.sort_order = "created_at_desc"` to every resource/file?

Or what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Checkout https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html#sorting

Answer (score 3):

There is no global configuration option available for this sort, and `ActiveAdmin` just simply use the default sort based on `primary_key` column `desc` as listed here https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/96c19f7d5d514dd37b49ab0293bac0a18a9672c5/lib/active_admin/resource.rb#L46

But we can achieve that by overriding that class as following:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin/resource.rb
ActiveAdmin::Resource.class_eval do
  def sort_order
    if resource_class.column_names.include?('created_at')
      @sort_order ||= 'created_at_desc'
    else
      # Fallback to default sort if model doesn't have created_at column
      @sort_order ||= (resource_class.respond_to?(:primary_key) ? resource_class.primary_key.to_s : 'id') + '_desc'
    end
  end
end
```